# what is internal resistance? can I get a simple explanation taking a dry cell as an example?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electrical-resistance

internal resistance is said to be the cause why we don't get current according to the EMF. it is said that the elements that make up the cell cause this resistance. still it seems confusing to me. can I get a more clear explanation with example?

Answer (score 0):

The electrons going through a conductor crash into the protons (not crash, rather they are electrically repelled at a distance, but the analogy is good enough to understand the phenomenon), which slow them down. That is why Ohm's law exists, a certain voltage creates a current in proportion to the resistance of the material.

The resistance varies depending on the material. This has to do with it's chemical structure. Depending on what it looks like, where the protons are and how many of them are there scooped together, the electrons will be slowed down a lot or very little.